# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: fr.la.juserright.metier.Ressource.<init>(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

My DAO always throws this exception: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: fr.la.juserright.metier.Ressource.<init>(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V`

RessourceDAO:

```
public List<Ressource> readAll() throws SQLException {
    List<Ressource> __ressource = new ArrayList<Ressource>();
    PreparedStatement _stmt = null;
    ResultSet _rs = null;

    try {
        _stmt = this.cnxUserRight.getCnx().prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM ressource");
        _rs = _stmt.executeQuery();
        while (_rs.next()) {
            Ressource _ressourcetmp = this.getRessource(_rs);
            __ressource.add(_ressourcetmp);
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != _rs) {
            _rs.close();
        }
        if (null != _stmt) {
            _stmt.close();
            this.cnxUserRight.closeCnx();
        }
    }
    return __ressource;
}

public Ressource getRessourceByPathForUpdate(String Path, int idressource)
        throws SQLException {
    Ressource _ressource = null;
    PreparedStatement _stmt = null;
    ResultSet _rs = null;

    try {
        _stmt = this.cnxUserRight
                .getCnx()
                .prepareStatement(
                        "SELECT * FROM ressource WHERE path like ? and idressource not like ?;");
        _stmt.setString(1, Path);
        _stmt.setInt(2, idressource);
        _rs = _stmt.executeQuery();
        if (_rs.next()) {
            _ressource = this.getRessource(_rs);
        } else {
            _ressource = null;
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != _rs) {
            _rs.close();
        }
        if (null != _stmt) {
            _stmt.close();
            this.cnxUserRight.closeCnx();
        }
    }
    return _ressource;
}

private Ressource getRessourceForChild(int _idChild) throws SQLException {
    Ressource _ressource = null;
    PreparedStatement _stmt = null;
    ResultSet _rs = null;
    try {
        _stmt = this.cnxUserRight.getCnx().prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM ressource " + "WHERE idressource = ("
                        + "SELECT idressource "
                        + "FROM ressource_ressource "
                        + "WHERE idressource_ressource = ?);");
        _stmt.setInt(1, _idChild);
        _rs = _stmt.executeQuery();
        if (_rs.next()) {
            _ressource = this.getRessource(_rs);
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != _rs) {
            _rs.close();
        }
        if (null != _stmt) {
            _stmt.close();
            this.cnxUserRight.closeCnx();
        }
    }
    return _ressource;
}

private List<Ressource> getRessourceForMOM(int _idmere) throws SQLException {
    List<Ressource> _ressource = new ArrayList<Ressource>();
    PreparedStatement _stmt = null;
    ResultSet _rs = null;

    String _sql = "SELECT * FROM ressource "
            + "WHERE idressource_ressource = ("
            + "SELECT idressource_ressource " + "FROM ressource_ressource "
            + "WHERE idressource = " + _idmere + ");";
    try {

        _stmt = this.cnxUserRight.getCnx().prepareStatement(_sql);
        _rs = _stmt.executeQuery();
        while (_rs.next()) {
            _ressource.add(this.getRessource(_rs));
        }
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != _rs) {
            _rs.close();
        }
        if (null != _stmt) {
            _stmt.close();
            this.cnxUserRight.closeCnx();
        }
    }
    return _ressource;
}

private Ressource getRessource(ResultSet _rs) throws SQLException {

    int _idRessource = _rs.getInt("idressource");
    String _path = _rs.getString("path");
    String _menu = _rs.getString("menu");
    String _description = _rs.getString("description");
    int _idressource_ressource = _rs.getInt("idressource_ressource");
    Ressource _ressource;
    if (_idressource_ressource != 0) {
        _ressource = new Ressource(_idRessource, _path, _menu,
                _description,
                this.getRessourceForChild(_idressource_ressource));
    } else {
        List<Ressource> _ressourceList = this
                .getRessourceForMOM(_idressource_ressource);
        _ressource = new Ressource(_idRessource, _path, _menu,
                _description, _ressourceList);
    }
    return _ressource;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
ATTENTION: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: fr.la.juserright.metier.Ressource.<init>(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
at fr.la.juserright.dao.RessourceDAO.getRessource(RessourceDAO.java:451)
at fr.la.juserright.dao.RessourceDAO.readAll(RessourceDAO.java:86)
at fr.la.juserright.service.RessourceModule.getAllRessource(RessourceModule.java:33)
at fr.la.juserright.service.ServiceUserRight.getAllRessource(ServiceUserRight.java:132)
at fr.la.juserright.managedbean.ressourceBean.refreshlist(ressourceBean.java:102)
at fr.la.juserright.managedbean.ressourceBean.<init>(ressourceBean.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:149)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:84)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:200)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.isLazy(DataTable.java:968)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:191)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:108)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:57)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:45)
at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

If you have an idea I'm interested.

Comment: It looks like a deployment problem - the current version of your `getRessource()` method doesn't use the offending constructor at all. Perhaps application server uses a different version of that class for some reason.

Comment: **Clean** Server/Project and restart.
as @BalusC told it's _run-time problem_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: fr.la.juserright.metier.Ressource.(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)V

This means that the following constructor of the `fr.la.juserright.metier.Ressource` class doesn't exist at all in the current runtime classpath.

```
public Ressource(int arg1, String arg2, String arg3, String arg4, int arg5) {}
```

But the code given so far doesn't seem to use that constructor anywhere. The two `new Resource()` calls in the `ResourceDAO` class use either `Ressource` or `List<Ressource>` as 5th argument.

Apparently the runtime classpath is dirty and you were running an outdated version of `RessourceDAO` all the time, while the `Ressource` class has properly been updated in the runtime classpath.

Clean, rebuild, redeploy and restart.

Note that this problem has **nothing** to do with JSF. The underlying exception is not coming from the `javax.faces` package, but just from the `java.lang` package, which basically indicates a basic Java language/runtime problem.